# Exec function working for one method, and not the other

Tags: python

Context: This is part of my code running inside of a class called commands, within a method called `Looper`. The idea for my code, is that when I input something into the Python command line, if its just one word, it runs the method with that name. If its greater 1 word, take takes the first word, make that the method command, and everything else is the argument.

```
cmd =  input("User>>> ")

cmdSplit = cmd.split()
lencmd = len(cmdSplit)

if (lencmd== 1):
    cmd = "commands." + cmd + "()"
    print(type(cmd))
    logging.debug("This is a length of 1")
    try:
        exec (cmd)
    except:
        print ("Not a valid command.")
```

It appears, when I type *chrome* (one of my methods posted below) into this line, `exec` breaks, and wont work. But if I use *hearth* (the other method, it works fine). I cant see any reason for chrome to not work, but hearth to work. Could `exec` just not like the word chrome?

```
def chrome():
    subprocess.Popen("chrome.bat", cwd=r"C:\cmdcommands")

def hearth():
    subprocess.Popen("hearth.bat", cwd=r"C:\cmdcommands")
```

output from my program:

```
User>>> chrome
<class 'str'>
DEBUG:root:This is a length of 1
Not a valid command
User>>> hearth
<class 'str'>
DEBUG:root:This is a length of 1
User>>>
```

Comment: What happens if you take away the `try` and `except`? What does IDLE say is happening?

Comment: What exception are you getting? Print that out.

Comment: Hanging `try/except` blocks are often the cause of all kinds of problems. If you want to use `try/except`, it's better to catch a specific kind of exception rather than blanket-catch all of them, since they mask problems exactly like the one you are describing.

Comment: Hi all. It appears to have been a bug. When I removed try and except, and rewrote it again ( albiet the exact same way) it started to work properly. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @mprat, Ill remember that for next time. Any advice how I would go around trying to get a blanket-catch all for errors?

Comment: @zhilothebest, the advice is not to. If something out of the ordinary happens, you want your program to flail, so you can actually deal with the error.

Comment: @zhilo I added an answer explaining the `try`/`except`.

Answer (score 0):

You used a hanging [`try:`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) and [`except:`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) statement, as mentioned in the comments.

Instead, specific [exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions) can be used to more accurately pinpoint the cause of issues in a Python program, such as a `ValueError` or `TypeError`.

Comment: Got it. This makes sense. Thank you!